# What is an EXC_EMULATION mach exception and what can trigger it?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, mach

The only information I can find in re: the `EXC_EMULATION` mach exception type is that it indicates

> Emulation support instruction encountered

but that is honestly pretty meaningless to me. How might one trigger an exception with this type?

I'm trying to test a tool that intends to detect mach exceptions in an application and would like to be able to test all of the possible types, but can't find any way to trigger this exception type.

Comment: Just a guess ... From the repo: https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu.git look at: `bsd/uxkern/ux_exception.c` as a starting point (I did a `grep -r` for `EXC_EMULATION`). The function of interest is `handle_ux_exception` Work up the call chain from there. It is called from `catch_mach_exception_raise` There are some 12 places that call/reference/define _that_ function.